# Avoiding DB hits

Tags: java

In my java application, I have a dropdown box which needs to be populated with values from a table *games*.

There is a separate functionality to add a game. (i:e. an insert in the table *games*)

The values of the dropdown wont be changing unless someone adds something in the database.

To develop the functionality to populate the dropdown box,

One way is to - 
Hit the table everytime a page load happens and fetch the data to populate the dropdown.

Is this an effective way? Can someone suggest me a better alternative design?

Comment: You could cache the result of the query and potentially save a lot of DB hits. You'd have to find a sensible way to invalidate the cache though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a cache... everytime a game is added you simply update your cache.
Implementing a cache is simple.

Comment: @webExplorer no need to implement one yourself. [Guava provides some neat implementations](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained)

Comment: LRUCache is also a common implementation

Answer (score 1):

If inserting data and retrieving it for the dropdown are performed in the same java application, then we might implement a kind of cache for the list of values.

So, we need a structure to store last list of games fetched from database, for example `List<Game>`, and a flag that is essentially an indicator for the event "someone added row to database".

Each time the page with dropdown is requested, we first check the indicator - if it is true, then we need to reload the list from database and set it back to false, if it is false - we can return the cached list.
Each time user adds entry to database, we set this indicator to true.

Also please be advised of possible concurrency problems when implementing that kind of cache.